# Appending created elements to different divs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

**JS** :

```
i.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var br1 = document.createElement("br");
  var div1 = document.createElement("div");
  div1.className = "input-group";

  var ipt1 = document.createElement("input");
  ipt1.type = "text";
  ipt1.className = "form-control";

  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.className = "input-group-addon";

  var ipt2 = document.createElement("input");
  ipt2.type = "text";
  ipt2.className = "form-control";

  div1.appendChild(ipt1);
  div1.appendChild(span);
  div1.appendChild(ipt2);
  divdiv.appendChild(div1);
  divdiv.appendChild(br1);
});

document.getElementById('modal2body').appendChild(divdiv);
```

However, when there are multiple `<i>`s, the `divdiv` is appended to the last one.

This is all in a for loop, which adds an `<i>` for each element in a list.

The list might look like `['customers','employees','managers','night-shifts']`

There needs to be an option to add the `input-group` to each one of these. (the i is a *FontAwesome* 'plus' icon).

The problem I have, is that clicking any of the icons, it will add the `input-group` to the `night-shift` list.

---

I thought I might need to use **dynamic variables** to fix this.

If it happens that this is the most effective solution, how can I achieve this?

Or is there a better way to do this ?

**Screenshot :**

[image: Screenshot]

In this screenshot, I clicked the **`+`** to the right of **`Customers`**

---

This code creates the original 4 input-groups (1 for each section) :

```js
var divdiv = document.createElement('div');
divdiv.id = 'd' + d;
var div1 = document.createElement('div')
div1.className = 'input-group';
var ipt1 = document.createElement('input');
ipt1.type = 'text';
ipt1.className = 'form-control'
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.className = 'input-group-addon';
var ipt2 = document.createElement('input');
ipt2.type = 'text';
ipt2.className = 'form-control'

var div2 = document.createElement('div');

var t = document.createElement('t');
t.className = 'helv-b grey'
t.style.fontSize = '15px';
t.textContent = inputstext[d];

div2.appendChild(t);

var i = document.createElement('i');
i.className = 'fa fa-plus';

i.style.float = 'right'
i.style.fontSize = '20px';
i.style.marginTop= '5px'
i.onmouseenter = i.style.opacity = "60%";
i.onmouseleave = i.style.opacity = "100%";
div2.appendChild(i);

var br1 = document.createElement('br');
var br2 = document.createElement('br');

divdiv.appendChild(div2);
divdiv.appendChild(br1);
div1.appendChild(ipt1);
div1.appendChild(span);
div1.appendChild(ipt2);
divdiv.appendChild(div1);
divdiv.appendChild(br2);

divdiv.id = 'f' + d;
```

(`inputstext` = `['Customers','Employees','Managers','Night-Shifts']`)

**HTML :**

```html
<div class="modal-body" id="modal2body">

</div>
```

---

### ###Update

**Screenshots :**
[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

I can't figure out how to fix these alignment issues and make them look like my original screenshot.

Also, how do I have 1 input-group already displayed for each section ?

Comment: can you better explain what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: @DCR of course. Ill post a screenshot.

Comment: nice screen shot, now what is it you are trying to do?  It might help if you show the html that goes with your code

Comment: Essentially, I need to add a new `input-group` to whichever section I click `+` on. So, in the screenshot, that 2nd input-group should have been added under **Customers**

Comment: where is divdiv defined?

Comment: without the html I don't see how I or anyone can help you

Comment: Ill add it now. Theres another JS bit which adds the original 4 inputs-groups (1 in each section), then a bit of html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the code which adds is event-driven, which means that it will run when the user clicks the add icon.  So when the add icon is click the value of `divdiv` will be the last element of array `"Night-Shifts"`.

Here is a way of doing it using arrays.

```js
var inputstext = ['customers', 'employees', 'managers', 'night-shifts']

var divdivArray = [];

var mainDiv = document.getElementById("modal2body");

for (var d = 0; d < inputstext.length; d++) {

  var divdiv = document.createElement('div');
  divdiv.id = 'd' + d;
  var div1 = document.createElement('div')
  div1.className = 'input-group';
  var ipt1 = document.createElement('input');
  ipt1.type = 'text';
  ipt1.className = 'form-control'
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.className = 'input-group-addon';
  var ipt2 = document.createElement('input');
  ipt2.type = 'text';
  ipt2.className = 'form-control'

  var div2 = document.createElement('div');

  var t = document.createElement('t');
  t.className = 'helv-b grey'
  t.style.fontSize = '15px';
  t.textContent = inputstext[d];

  div2.appendChild(t);

  var i = document.createElement('i');
  i.className = 'fa fa-plus';


  i.style.float = 'right'
  i.style.fontSize = '20px';
  i.style.marginTop = '5px'
  i.onmouseenter = i.style.opacity = "60%";
  i.onmouseleave = i.style.opacity = "100%";
  i.setAttribute("index", d)
  div2.appendChild(i);

  var br1 = document.createElement('br');
  var br2 = document.createElement('br');

  divdiv.appendChild(div2);
  divdiv.appendChild(br1);
  div1.appendChild(ipt1);
  div1.appendChild(span);
  div1.appendChild(ipt2);
  divdiv.appendChild(div1);
  divdiv.appendChild(br2);

  divdiv.id = 'f' + d;
  mainDiv.appendChild(divdiv)

  divdivArray.push(divdiv);

  i.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var br1 = document.createElement("br");
    var div1 = document.createElement("div");
    div1.className = "input-group";

    var ipt1 = document.createElement("input");
    ipt1.type = "text";
    ipt1.className = "form-control";

    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.className = "input-group-addon";

    var ipt2 = document.createElement("input");
    ipt2.type = "text";
    ipt2.className = "form-control";

    div1.appendChild(ipt1);
    div1.appendChild(span);
    div1.appendChild(ipt2);
    var index = this.getAttribute("index");
    divdivArray[index].appendChild(div1);
    divdivArray[index].appendChild(br1);
  });
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<div class="modal-body" id="modal2body" style="display: inline-block;">

</div>
<html>
```

Here I save every `divdiv` inside the array. And also add an `index` attribute to the `<i>` element so when it is clicked you can know which `divdiv` you want to edit.

Comment: Hello, thanks for this - please see my updated question; I can't figure out some alignment issues?

Comment: Can you tell me what value does the d variable has?. Do you use d as an iterator on your loop?

Comment: Yes i also used it for getting the title from the list

Comment: @Arr - I edited my answer. Hopefully, it will solve your problem.